# Swiping between UITableViewController detail items

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` derived class. In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, I create a detail view controller `vc` and push it with `[self.navigationController pushViewController: vc animated: YES];`.

On that detail view, I want to be able to swipe left and right and go to the previous/next item detail, or back to the table view if it's on the first/last item. I implemented the swipe and back functionality using `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];`, but I'm not sure about how to implement the detail -> detail paging. I thought about using the same pop, then calling `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but tracking and modifying the index path and tracking the tableView seems like a clunky way. Is there a better way?

Also, when I pop the view controller, it always slides off to the right. Is there a way to animate it sliding off to the left (to simulate a right to left swipe on the last item)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do what you're trying to do is to present your detail contents in a UIPageViewController. It is a collection view controller, kind of like a table view controller. It has a delegate and data source like a table view does. It asks you to give it view controllers that present pages of content. You can set it up to slide from page to page or page curl, and optionally add a book spine. There is a sample app from Apple called PhotoScroller that shows how to set up a page view controller for sliding back and forth. It does a lot more than that, but you can ignore the content view controllers it uses and substitute your own detail view controllers.

You would share the data model between the table view and the page view controller.